# Any ideas/ examples on how to use the detect-intent api on dialogflow to read the intent from a json file?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Any idea or examples as to how to detect intent using the Dialogflow detect-intent api(https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) from a JSON file?
Thank you in advance.

The function is supposed to be hosted on Firebase functions and I am using nodejs.

I will try to explain what I am trying to do. 
So I have a bunch of Intents on Dialogflow already. And I know that the starting intent is going to be the Welcome intent. After the Welcome Intent I want to shape the conversation according to the intent list on the json file.

The entire flow is something like this.

- Bot: Hello, What form would you like to fill up today?
- User: Leave form

*Dialogflow matches the leave form with the leave form entity and pulls the leave form json from the storage. The json will contain the fields that are required to be filled up for the form*

- Bot: Hi, so I would need some details to fill this form.
- Bot: Let's start with your name ..... etc etc

So, instead of detecting the intent from the user's side, I need to detect what intent, from the json. The Webhook fulfillment is currently being hosted on Firebase functions and the json is being stored on Firebase Storage(not Database)

Comment: What do you mean by "use it from a JSON file"? Can you [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57014219/edit) to give examples of how you want things to work and what you're trying to do? As your question stands now, it isn't very clear.

Comment: I will try to explain what I am trying to do. So I have a bunch of Intents on Dialogflow already. And I know that the starting intent is going to be the Welcome intent. After the Welcome Intent I want to shape the conversation according to the intent list on the json file.

The entire flow is something like this. Bot: Hello, What form would you like to fill up today? User: Leave form

*** Dialogflow matches the leave form with the leave form entity and pulls the leave form json from the storage. The json will contain the fields that are required to be filled up for the form ******

Comment: Bot: Hi, so I would need some details to fill this form. Bot: Let's start with your name ..... etc etc

So, instead of detecting the intent from the user's side, I need to detect what intent, from the json. The Webhook fulfillment is currently being hosted on Firebase functions and the json is being stored on Firebase Storage(not Database)

Comment: this libraray might help, https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-helper I wrote this library on the top of dialogflow rest client

Answer (score 0):

The Detect Intent API only helps you to detect the intent from the text sent by you to the Dialogflow agent using the API. So you cannot read the intent from the JSON file using the Detect Intent API, your intent must be imported to the Dialogflow agent.

Comment: And I intend to do exactly that. I am importing (into the Webhook fulfillment)  a JSON that has the intents that I need to call ( after the user chooses what it wants to do). The only thing I am sure about is that the Intents are limited. But the order in which they are called are completely arbitrary. So, I need help with the detect_intent API to detect what Intents I need to call. And  I can't find a single decent example on it. And the documentation on it highly confusing.

Comment: this libraray might help, https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-helper I wrote this library on the top of dialogflow rest client